# Flex Blaze DS and JPA - lazy-loading issues

Tags: java, apache-flex, reflection, jpa, blazeds

I am developing an application in Flex, using Blaze DS to communicate with a Java back-end, which provides persistence via JPA (Eclipse Link).

I am encountering issues when passing JPA entities to Flex via Blaze DS. Blaze DS uses reflection to convert the JPA entity into an ObjectProxy (effectively a HashMap) by calling all getter methods on the entity. This includes any lazy-initialised one/many-to-many relationships.

You can probably see where I am going. If I pass a single object through JPA this will call all one/many-to-many methods on this object. For each returned object if they have one/many-to-many relationships they will be called too. As such, by passing back a single JPA entity I actually end up doing multiple database calls and passing all related entries back as a single ObjectProxy instance!

My solution to date is to create a translator to convert each entity to an ObjectProxy and vice-versa. This is clearly cumbersome and there must be a better way.

Thoughts please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, lazy-loading is not easy to accomplish with Flash clients.  There are some working solutions, like [dpHibernate](http://blog.engage-encore.com/index.php/2009/05/13/blazeds-lazy-loading/), but so far all the different solutions I have tested fall short of what you would expect in terms of performance and ease of use.

So in my experience, it is the best and most reliable solution to always use [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s, which adds the benefit of cleanly separating the database and view layers.  This necessitates, though, that you implement either eager loading, or a second server round trip to resolve your many-to-many relations, as well as a good deal more boilerplate code to copy the DAO and DTO field values.

Which one to choose depends on your use case: Sometimes getting only the main object's fields might be enough, then you could simply omit the List of related objects from your DTO (transfer only those values you need for your query).  Sometimes you may actually need the entire list of related entities, and then you could get it via eager loading, or by setting up a second remote object to find only the list.

Comment: Thanks for your response @weltraumpirat. I think the DTO abstraction you suggest is actually what I've been doing in my translator objects and I think this is probably the best option available to me given dpHibernate is not an option for this project. I've had a look at creating a generic translator based on custom annotations in my JPA entities and I think this is going to do what I need, albeit this means a lot of boiler-plate code to achieve what I am trying to. Still, better than repeating the field definitions in several different places.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could consider using [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org) instead of BlazeDS: GraniteDS has a much more powerful [data management](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.datamanagement.html) stack than BlazeDS (it competes more with LCDS) and fully support lazy-loading for all major JPA engines: Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA, etc.

Moreover, GraniteDS has a great client-side [transparent lazy loading](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.datamanagement.html#data.lazyloading) feature and even a so-called [*reverse* lazy-loading](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.datamanagement.html#data.reverselazyloading) mechanism.

And you don't need any kind of intermediate DTOs: it serializes JPA entities as is and uses code-generated ActionScript beans on the client-side to keep their initialization states.

Comment: Sounds awesome. Maybe I'll use that next time. We're a bit too far down the line in this project...

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink also provides a copyObject() API that allows you to give a copy group of exactly what attribute you want.  You could then use this copy to avoid having the relationships that you do not want.

If you have a detached object, you could just null out the fields that you do not want as well, or use a DTO.